# How to expose a member's properties as the owner's own or inherit by receiving instance of parent's class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, design-patterns, properties

I'm receiving an object of class Foo from an API, say:

`Foo instance = SomeoneElsesAPI.GetFooInstance(id);`

I need use Foo, but also add properties to it of my own. The way I can think of doing this is:

```
class Bar{
    private Foo actual;
    public Bar(Foo actual)
    {
        this.actual = actual;
    }

    public string Prop1 { get {return actual.Prop1; } }
    public string Prop2 { get {return actual.Prop2; } }
    //...
    public string Prop23 { get {return actual.Prop23; } }

    public string MyOwnProperty1 { get { return ExternalSource.LoadInfo(actual.Id) } }
}
```

It feels dirty!

Is there anyone out there that knows how to cleanly expose members of a member as a class's own, or maybe how to extend Foo and have Bar's constructor take an instance of Foo?

Answer (score 2):

This is the decorator pattern. It's perfectly fine for encapsulating another class within a class, especially if you want to expose less properties. If you use resharper, you can make the implementation easier with the Alt+Insert shortcut and selecting "Delegating Members" in the resulting context menu.

Comment: But isn't there any syntactic sugar out there to reduce all the trash code this produces?

I'm thinking about python's `__getattr__`
`def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.actual, name)`
That would give me exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but simple inheritance would do the job for you:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
     public string MyOwnProperty1 { get { return ExternalSource.LoadInfo(actual.Id) } }
}
```

You should be good to go. The `Prop1`,`Prop2` and `Prop23` etc are there for you due to inheritance, you can override if you need to.

Comment: The special thing with this situation is I'm given an object of type Foo, not Bar. I don't have control over the object's creation.